# I made a copy of the list but when I make a change to the copy, the original list still changes. I don't understand why

Tags: python, list, for-loop, copy, mutable

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 5], [5, 6, 8]]
p = l.copy()
for indx, value in enumerate(p):
    del value[0]
print(l)
print(p)
```

Output: [[2, 3], [2, 3, 5], [6, 8]]
        [[2, 3], [2, 3, 5], [6, 8]]

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: You need to make a deepcopy, i.e. copy the inner lists as well.

Comment: @zamir What version are you on?

Comment: @iz_ getting same error on both Python 3.6.5 & Python 2.7.15

Comment: @zamir no you aren't. That would only be an error on Python 2.

Comment: my bad sorry did not notice I was on 2.7.15 at first